# Compare two tables input and then output based upon id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

#### Background

My problem:  I have two tables with information which may or may not exist in both tables. Mainly id, name and account number.

Table Structure:

```
 Table 1                 Table 2
id |  a_name |num      id  |  b_name   | num
-----------------------------------------------
1   |  Bob   | 222  |   1  |   same    | 123 
2   |  Jane  | 1a3  |   2  |   Joe     | 6a4 
3   |  same  | 321  |   3  |   Max     | 123
4   |  same  | 123  |   4  |   same    | 222
```

What I must first do is check to see if the name exists from table 1 to table 2, as well as make sure table 2 doesn't have any entries existing in table 1.  However, I must also compare and contrast the corresponding account number so that the output would be similar to:

```
 Final Table/Array 
id  |  name   |num
---------------------
1   |  Bob   | 222
2   |  Jane  | 1a3
3   |  Joe   | 6a4
4   |  Max   | 123 
5   |  same  | 123  
6   |  same  | 222  
7   |  same  | 321
```

After I compare and contrast the two tables, I need to be able to pull the id correlating to the correct table, and then output those into a selector.

Any suggestions on how to proceed, and some tips on coding it correctly?

I was thinking to loop them both into separate arrays, use two different in_array statements, and then output the responses based upon a if -else statement...BUT I KNOW this is definately not gonna work because I wont know which table they came from.

Recommendations on best methods?  I don't want to show you the code I have currently because its a mindboggler that I cant even understand right now.

#### Issue Clarification:

I only need to output a single distinct (non duplicate) list of names (and numbers) and be able to identify 1) which table its from and 2) the id of the entry from the original table so that I can pull all columns with the corresponding id.

Comment: You want check if a name is in both tables and also make sure there are no names in both tables? What do you mean?

Comment: When you put them into an array, you do know where they come from and hence your method is gonna work. Problem?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify.  I only need to output a single distinct (non duplicate) list of names and be able to identify 1) which table its from and 2) its id.

Comment: @kingkero  there are more headers than the example shows, so to add a * for the select statement when adding it to an array is going to add information that is un-needed.

Comment: Is a_name unique within Table 1? Similarly, is b_name unique within Table 2 ?

Comment: @Jimzie  I was hoping to use this function on different pages, in certain cases, Table 1 has a_name and table 2 has b_name.  BUT i will need to use an extremely similar function where table 1 & 2 may have the same header name.... Couldn't the headers to check be defined using variables?

Comment: Yes you can of course substitute things with variables. You appear to not have answered my question... so are the CONTENTS of each of these columns under inspection unique within the table, or can "Bob" appear twice in the Table 1 (with a different ID) ?

Comment: @Jimzie  Unfortunately, yes, the name Bob can sometimes appear twice in the same table.  However, there is another field which I have omitted for example purposes named "location", which can be a number or a combination of letters, or both (or NULL :-(  ).  Is this useful?

Comment: @hawkhorrow - sort of, maybe... but this "second Bob" at a presumably different location, is really the first Bob, yes? I do have a solution if that statement was true; I would need to tweak that solution if there was a Bob A., a Bob B., a Bob C. -- and the surnames were in a different column. The real question is "how do you determine what is a duplicate?", and that affects implementation syntax, but not technique.

Comment: @Jimzie   Yes, bob will always be bob.  But lets say table 1 has name: bob location: here   - table 2 may have two entries (or vice versa) such as name: bob location: here, as well as name: bob location: there

Answer (score 0):

> I only need to output a single distinct (non duplicate) list of names and be able to identify 1) which table its from and 2) its id.

This isn't possible given these conditions you've stated:

1. A table may have the same name more than once.
2. A name may appear in each table.

How is it possible to produce a single list of names with a single source table and id? If you are choosing one of the records with the same name as a "winner", then you need to state the criteria for one `(table, id)` pair being favored over another for a given name.

For example, the following query will produce your desired output, but as far as I can see such a list is useless

```sql
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT a_name AS name, 'table1' AS table, id FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b_name AS name, 'table2' AS table, id FROM table2)
AS t1 GROUP BY name
```

Given your sample data, this query will produce the following results of dubious utility:

```
name | table  | id
-----+--------+---
Bob  | table1 | 1
Jane | table1 | 2
Joe  | table2 | 2
Max  | table2 | 3
same | table2 | 4
```

These results satisfy your criteria: No names are duplicated, and each name has one (of many possible) source table and id. But to what end?

If your objective is to explore all possible correlations between matching names in different tables, perhaps you should use a full outer join (emulated in MySQL with a union between a left and right outer join).

```sql
SELECT table1.id AS a_id, a_name, table1.num AS a_num,
  table2.id AS b_id, b_name, table2.num AS b_num
  FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON a_name=b_name
UNION ALL
SELECT table1.id AS a_id, a_name, table1.num AS a_num,
  table2.id AS b_id, b_name, table2.num AS b_num
  FROM table1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2 ON a_name=b_name
```

```
| a_id | a_name | a_num| b_id  | b_name | b_num  |
+------+--------+------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1    | Bob    | 222  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| 2    | Jane   | 1a3  | NULL  | NULL   | NULL   |
| 3    | same   | 321  | 1     | same   | 123    |
| 3    | same   | 321  | 4     | same   | 222    |
| 4    | same   | 123  | 1     | same   | 123    |
| 4    | same   | 123  | 4     | same   | 222    |
| 3    | same   | 321  | 1     | same   | 123    |
| 4    | same   | 123  | 1     | same   | 123    |
| NULL | NULL   | NULL | 2     | Joe    | 6a4    |
| NULL | NULL   | NULL | 3     | Max    | 123    |
| 3    | same   | 321  | 4     | same   | 222    |
| 4    | same   | 123  | 4     | same   | 222    |
```

Comment: I better explained the question, and I appreciate your answer, but due to the context of the output, (I think possibly I posted something similar earlier), your solution will not work for my project.  Thank you again.

Comment: I know it would be no easy solution, but for the scope of the project, something like this would need to be accomplished.... Can you suggest any other methodology or documentation to look into?

Comment: You are more in need of clear thinking about the problem and what you are trying to accomplish then any magic technique. The hard part about this problem is not the programming but deciding what rules you want to use to merge these two lists and what to do about duplicates.

Comment: a few days ago you answered one of my other questions which...for lack of a better word was arse-backwards....  though you might appreciate seeing the solution i came up with:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775444/entry-of-items-checking-sharing-optimization-from-post-form    (please +1 if you like it)

Comment: and ill get back to you on this current issue....i'll have to figure something out.  maybe an additional table for beta implementation could be used